# Change the script to also support Mouse drag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a touch script to rotate the camera around the orbit. I am facing difficulty to add mouse click and drag function as well more like an || function to this script. The mouse function has `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` which detects the mouse position. How do I achieve it?

```
    private float xDeg = 0.0f;
    private float yDeg = 0.0f;
    private float currentDistance;
    private float desiredDistance;
    private Quaternion currentRotation;
    private Quaternion desiredRotation;
    private Quaternion rotation;
    private Vector3 position;
    public float zoomDampening = 5.0f;
    public float rotationSensitivity = 1f;
 
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount==1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) //Add mouse function
        {
            Vector2 touchposition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
 
           
            xDeg += touchposition.x * 20f * 0.002f;
           
            yDeg -= touchposition.y * 20f * 0.002f;
            yDeg = ClampAngle(yDeg, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
        }
       
        desiredRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg, xDeg, 0);
        currentRotation = transform.localRotation;
        rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, desiredRotation, Time.deltaTime * zoomDampening);
        transform.localRotation = rotation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add Mouse X and Mouse Y axis to the floating variable and then it works as expected. The addition in the code is given below with the else statement:

```
                else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
                xDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSensitivity;
                yDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSensitivity;
                }
```

and for anyone who requires the full solution of mouse click and drag/touch and move and zoom in/out:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class CameraOrbit : MonoBehaviour {
 
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 targetOffset;
    public float distance = 5.0f;
    public float maxDistance = 20;
    public float minDistance = .6f;
    public float xSpeed = 5.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 5.0f;
    public int yMinLimit = -80;
    public int yMaxLimit = 80;
    public float zoomRate = 10.0f;
    public float panSpeed = 0.3f;
    public float zoomDampening = 5.0f;
 
    private float xDeg = 0.0f;
    private float yDeg = 0.0f;
    private float currentDistance;
    private float desiredDistance;
    private Quaternion currentRotation;
    private Quaternion desiredRotation;
    private Quaternion rotation;
    private Vector3 position;
 
    private Vector3 FirstPosition;
    private Vector3 SecondPosition;
    private Vector3 delta;
    private Vector3 lastOffset;
    private Vector3 lastOffsettemp;

    public float rotationSensitivity = 1f;

 
 
    void Start() 
    {
        position = transform.localPosition;
        rotation = transform.localRotation;
        currentRotation = transform.localRotation;
        desiredRotation = transform.localRotation;

        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
        currentDistance = distance;
        desiredDistance = distance;


        xDeg = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.right, transform.right);
        yDeg = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, transform.up);
    }
    void OnEnable() { Init(); }
 
    public void Init()
    {
        // //If there is no target, create a temporary target at 'distance' from the cameras current viewpoint
        if (!target)
        {
            GameObject go = new GameObject("Cam Target");
            go.transform.position = transform.position + (transform.forward * distance);
            target = go.transform;
        }
 
       
    }
 
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch(1).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch (0);
 
            Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch (1);
 
 
            Vector2 touchZeroPreviousPosition = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
            Vector2 touchOnePreviousPosition = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;
 
 
 
            float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPreviousPosition - touchOnePreviousPosition).magnitude;
 
            float TouchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;
 
 
 
            float deltaMagDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - TouchDeltaMag;
 
            desiredDistance += deltaMagDiff * Time.deltaTime * zoomRate * 0.0025f * Mathf.Abs(desiredDistance);
        }

        if (Input.touchCount==1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Vector2 touchposition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

            //CHANGE HERE
            xDeg += touchposition.x * xSpeed * 0.002f;
            //CHANGE HERE
            yDeg -= touchposition.y * ySpeed * 0.002f;
            yDeg = ClampAngle(yDeg, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
 
        }
        else
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
                xDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSensitivity;
                yDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSensitivity;
            }
        
        desiredRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg, xDeg, 0);
        currentRotation = transform.localRotation;
        rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, desiredRotation, Time.deltaTime * zoomDampening);
        transform.localRotation = rotation;
 
 
        ////////Orbit Position
 
        // affect the desired Zoom distance if we roll the scrollwheel
        desiredDistance = Mathf.Clamp(desiredDistance, minDistance, maxDistance);
        currentDistance = Mathf.Lerp(currentDistance, desiredDistance, Time.deltaTime * zoomDampening);
 
        position = target.position - (rotation * Vector3.forward * currentDistance );
 
        position = position - targetOffset;
 
        transform.position = position;


    }
    private static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360)
            angle += 360;
        if (angle > 360)
            angle -= 360;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```